# Using Eclipse ADT I want to be able to create and use one .txt file with multiple activities

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am searching for an easy way to use one .txt file created in the Main_Activity to be updated in another activity.
Basically i want to be able to use one txt file throughout multiple activities.
I just need basic coding principals for doing this.

Notes:
I have already created the .txt file in the Main_Activity, 
Now I have a second activity that should then be able to update the string in the .txt file created in the Main_Activity.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Eclipse. This is an Android question. File IO in Android is basically the same as in Java, with the exception that you need to declare the write permissions in the Android Manifest.

Comment: for your requirement , i recommend you to use shared preferences instead of of text files.

Comment: .....and by the way.....don´t use eclipse it is not supported anymore. Use android studio....

Comment: You can of course use a file in any and in as much activities as you want. I do not understand which problem you have with that. Please explain.

Comment: `don´t use eclipse it is not supported anymore.` Eclipse does the work here up to Android 7.1.1. And it is much faster then Android Studio.